# Why does ruby on rails 4 not reload anything in head tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several web pages. When I click on regular links they direct me to the correct page but it keeps the css and javascript from the previous page. This is not ideal, as the various pages need to have separate javascript files.

When i specify: `layout false` and put all the html code with head and included links and scripts in the view, the same issue occurs. Is there something i'm missing? I do use `redirect` in the controllers to display a fair amount of content. Is there any arguments to render to specify weather the whole page should be loaded.

Here is an example home view I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <% stylesheet_link_tag 'home', media: 'all'%>
</head>
<body>
  <%= link_to other_path %>
</body>
</html>
```

and the other view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project</title>
  <% stylesheet_link_tag 'other', media: 'all'%>
</head>
<body>
  <%= link_to home_path %>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the link to the second view, the stylesheet does not change.

EDIT: I know this might be violating the DRY part of rails, however I was unsuccessful with the head tag in the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head. Think CGI vs persistent process.

Try going to your `Gemfile` and commenting/removing the following gem that was introduced in Rails 4:

```
gem 'turbolinks'
```

For more information see the gem's github repo: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Comment: Found this just after posting my question. Thanks!